# Connecting RadioStream and a MP3 decoder

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to build an arduino web radio for reading the stream and decoding the stream I have the following two methods for writing and reading the stream, that need to be connected, but I can't think of a good way:

In this method we read the radio stream and write its content to a 32 byte buffer.

```
 uint8_t buff[32];
 // from the server, read them and print them:
while (true)
{
    int ret = client.read(buff, sizeof(buff) / 2 );
    if (ret <= 0)
    break;
    for(int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
    {//instead of Serial write we need to do something with the contents of this buffer

        Serial.write((char)buff[i]);
    }
}
```

The next method takes the binary stream from the web radio and decodes it:

```
    int getMoreData(uint8_t *writeHere, int available)
    {
  /* TODO: write up to 'available' bytes of MP3 data 
   * to the location 'writeHere'. Return the actual number of bytes
   * that were written
   */}
```

The two methods need to be interconnected, but I'm not sure how.

Thank you!

Comment: By "stream", you don't mean an [`iostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) do you?

Comment: How does that matter in the end i have just two byte buffers that need to read from and written to.

Comment: `iostream` has a special function in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what I needed here was a buffer that could be filled and read asynchronous.

Or in other words a consumer and producer that works at different speeds.

So what worked for me was a standard Ring Buffer, for which a wide variety of implementations is available for almost every platform (including arduino)